# DB2 SQL replication: drop member command is not working

Tags: db2, replication

I am trying to drop a member from a subscription set. below command seems to be correct but getting the error. Please check and assist ?

I have set the capture, control and apply server before running drop member command.

```
DROP MEMBER FROM SETNAME SET22 APPLYQUAL MYQUAL22 
SOURCE DB2WCS.CATENTDESC TARGET DB2WCS.CATENTDESC;
```

> ASN1950E  ASNCLP : An unexpected token "SETNAME" was found. Valid
>   tokens include "FROM".
>
> ASN1954E  ASNCLP : Command failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the update.
IBM support suggested below workaround,

Regarding the problem in question, I've found an APAR fixed in Fixpack 9.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR57130

If you can't upgrade to FP9, there're 2 workarounds, although are not shown in APAR:

1.- Specify a second "FROM" into the ASNCLP like

DROP MEMBER FROM FROM SETNAME ... APPLYQUAL ... SOURCE ... TARGET ...

2.- Use the INCLUDE HISTORY clause like:
  DROP MEMBER INCLUDE HISTORY FROM SETNAME ....

Answer (score 0):

If the Db2 server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, and is either Version 10.5.0.8 or V11.1 then you may be experiencing this [bug](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR57130). You might want to contact IBM support.

Comment: Thanks for the update.
IBM support suggested below workaround,
Regarding the problem in question, I've found an APAR fixed in Fixpack 9.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR57130

If you can't upgrade to FP9, there're 2 workarounds, although are not shown in APAR:

1.- Specify a second "FROM" into the ASNCLP like
 
DROP MEMBER FROM FROM SETNAME ... APPLYQUAL ... SOURCE ... TARGET ...

2.- Use the INCLUDE HISTORY clause like:
  DROP MEMBER INCLUDE HISTORY FROM SETNAME ....